# Is it always nessasary to call gpio_free()?

Tags: gpio

Is it always necessary to free a GPIO pin after you have requested it? What does freeing a GPIO pin do and what happens if you don't call gpio_free()?

Comment: Take a look at https://lwn.net/Articles/532714/ . It might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling gpio_free() means to disconnect it from power (GND or 3V3) if it is set to output type. I have written a c program which needs a ctrl+c keyboard interrupt to quit, so it cannot free the used pins, this means there is still voltage on the pins when te program quits, but when I restart it it resets the pins, so not calling gpio free does not stop any code from working, but the pins stay connected to power after quit.